# Fixed Footer in Android API 22 (Android 5.1 (Lollipop))

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to Android and trying to develop an app with Android API 22. I am not able to get a fixed footer. How to make the footer fixed with scrollable content in the middle of the activity? What are attributes to set and how?

I have solution like - setting 'android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"' which might work for previous API levels but now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`, it works in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this...

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- The content: this is scrollable -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        style="@style/Footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <!-- Stuff to go in your footer -->

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Footer" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar" >
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|end</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
</style>
```

**v21/styles**:

```
<style name="AppTheme.LinearLayout.Footer" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar" >
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|end</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

This creates a nice-looking footer, with elevation on Lollipop+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something very similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <ScrollView
      android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/footer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```